# Timezone unknown in Rstudio

Tags: r

An error is preventing me from knitting my document.

The error I receive is

```
Quitting from lines 79-81 (Project_GYMBO.Rmd) 
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: (converted from warning) unknown timezone 'default/America/Toronto'.
```

The lines that cause the error are quite simple.

```
weight.rm %>% mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime)) %>% head
```

The data looks like

```
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
    datetime = c("2017-10-09 16:03:09", "2017-10-09 15:36:23",
                 "2017-10-09 15:04:53", "2017-10-09 13:01:23",
                 "2017-10-09 12:33:16", "2017-10-09 12:05:41"),
          WR = c(87, 69, 61, 51, 50, 48)
)
```

Which gives me

```
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'default/America/Toronto'
```

I'm currently working from Toronto.

From what I can tell, it is because R can not determine my timezone correctly.  When I call `Sys.timezone()`, I get NA.

Is this a known problem?  Can anyone tell me why R can't understand my timezone?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem by copy/pasting ur data

Comment: `lubridate::ymd_hms`'s `tz` parameter defaults to `"UTC"`, so this is...odd. It also doesn't make sense that `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct` is getting called. Some necessary context is apparently missing.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this R bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17307), this was a problem with macOS 10.3. While the bug report is closed as fixed, the [R Installation and Administration manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#High-Sierra) for R version 3.4.2 lists it as a known issue. It appears to be fixed in the current development version ([NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/NEWS.html), see first note at the top).

For now, it seems like the best (though not particularly robust) solution is to add the following to your `~/.Rprofile`:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "America/Toronto")
```

Of course, anyone not in the `America/Toronto` timezone would replace that with their actual timezone. There are also instructions at the bug link for fixing when you compile R, or you could use the current development version, which may be better options for some situations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this has been resolved in R 3.4.3. You can read more about it in the [release news](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-3.4.3.html).

**Edit:** Below is the related part of the release notes.

> **INSTALLATION on a UNIX-ALIKE**
>
> A workaround has been added for the changes in location of time-zone files in macOS 10.13 'High Sierra' and again in 10.13.1, so the default time zone is deduced correctly from the system setting when R is configured with --with-internal-tzcode (the default on macOS).